# save the value of checkbox to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

Hi i have checkbox then i want to save the value of this checkbox using php but the value is generated using javascrip. How can save that vaue using php?

Checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='calibrate' onclick='OnChangeCheckbox(this), enable_text(this.checked)' id='myCheckbox' />
<input type="submit" value="UPDATE" id="gobutton" style="float: right; padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px; margin-right: 6px;" />
```

Javascript:

```
    function OnChangeCheckbox (checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "yes";                                     
        }else {                                
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "no";                                                
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the element `#val`?

Comment: You'll have to use ajax to send the value back when the user changes the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try and add this line in your process action "DONOT NEED JAVASCRIPT IN YOUR CASE USE PHP INSTEAD" remove javascript onclick

```
<?php $calibrate = isset($_POST['calibrate']) ? 'yes' : 'no' ; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the value from javascript to a php file to save it.This can be done using an ajax call as:

```
function OnChangeCheckbox (checkbox) {
   var checkvalue="";
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        checkvalue = document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "yes";
    }else {                                
        checkvalue = document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "no";
    }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method="POST";
var url="url-of-your-php-file";
var data="checkvalue="+checkvalue;
xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
{ 
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
    { 
       //debugger;
       var response=xhr.responseText;                 
       if(response.indexOf('Error') !=-1)
       {
           alert("Error!");
       }
       else
       {
          alert("Data successfully sent!");                  

       }

    }
}
```

and in your php file you can get the data sent from here as $_POST['checkvalue'], then you can use it to save in the database.

Comment: you have to place this code in your javascript with the url variable having the path to your php file where you want to post it, it will output "Data successfully sent!" in alert if data gets posted otherwise "Error!"

Answer (score 0):

Don' need to use java script for this you can also get it by php 
By : `<?php echo isset($_POST[calibrate]) ? "checked" : "not checked";  ?>`

If Still you want to use JS then you can set value in input using .val() and can get it by post:

```
<?php echo $_post['checkbox_val']; ?>

<input type="hidden" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" >
<input type='checkbox' name='calibrate' onclick='OnChangeCheckbox(this), enable_text(this.checked)' id='myCheckbox' />

    function OnChangeCheckbox (checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "yes";
            document.getElementById("checkbox_val").val = "checked";
        }else {                                
            document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "no";  
            document.getElementById("checkbox_val").val = "not_checked";                                              
        }
}
```